# Border-radius is ignored when scale property is added on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a card component that includes an image with some text below. When the user hovers on any part of the card, the image grows by 5% (`transform: scale(1.05)`) - this behaviour works as expected.

But I cannot figure out why, when hovering on the card, why the border-radius on the image is then removed (most noticeable at the top). As the image should never grow outside of its container, the border should not change on hover.

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
}

.img-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
}

.card-container:hover .img-wrapper img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.text-wrapper {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="card-container">
   <div class="img-wrapper">
     <img src="https://placekitten.com/1440/671" />
   </div>
   <div class="text-wrapper">
     hello
   </div>
 </div>
```

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Remove the `.img-wrapper img { transform: scale(1.05); }` - it makes your image overflow the container

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `border-radius` from `.img-wrapper img` and add it to `.img-wrapper`
that's because you are giving border-radius to an image that is being zoomed in hover

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
}

.img-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
     border-radius: 0.75rem;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-container:hover .img-wrapper img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.text-wrapper {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
   <div class="img-wrapper">
     <img src="https://placekitten.com/1440/671" />
   </div>
   <div class="text-wrapper">
     hello
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the border-radius to the parent element of the image, not to the image.

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
}

.img-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0.75rem;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-container:hover .img-wrapper img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.text-wrapper {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="card-container">
   <div class="img-wrapper">
     <img src="https://placekitten.com/1440/671" />
   </div>
   <div class="text-wrapper">
     hello
   </div>
 </div>
```